Quarto panel layout outputs multiple tables instead of one when using kable_styling
I'm trying to display two tables in one using Quarto's "panel" layout facility. I need to style the tables and use kable_styling to that end. When doing so I obtain two tables with the same caption instead of the expected two sub-tables with their respective sub-captions under a main caption.
Code:
#| label: tbl-repex
#| tbl-cap: "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
#| tbl-subcap: 
#|     - "officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum"
#|     - "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident sunt in culpa"
#| layout-nrows: 2
#| echo: false

pacman::p_load(knitr, kableExtra)

colnames <- c("lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", "amet", "consectetur")
ncol <- NROW(colnames)
nrow <- 10
align <- c(rep("l", ncol / 2), rep("r", ncol / 2))
font_size <- 7

matrix(rnorm(ncol * nrow), nrow = nrow) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  kable(col.names = colnames, align = align) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size =font_size)
  
matrix(rnorm(ncol * nrow), nrow = nrow) %>% as.data.frame() %>%
  kable(col.names = colnames, align = align) %>%
  kable_styling(font_size =font_size)

Output:


Related (and still open) GH issues: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/4517 and https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/9586.
